# How can i sort before finding and limiting in a collection?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Which method of `pymongo` executes first? `sort` or `limit`?

I've a big collection where i need to filter for a specific discount category ("X"), e.g:

```
{"discount_value": 1, "name": "promotion_1", "category": ["X"]},
{"discount_value": 10, "name": "promotion_10", "category": ["X", "Y"]},
{"discount_value": 15, "name": "promotion_15", "category": ["X", "Y", "Z"]}
```

But the query must filter all documents by `discount_values` retrieving the bigger ones, lets say that i need to `limit` the query by 2:

```
.find({"category": {"$in": ["X"]}})
.limit(2)
.sort("discount_value", pymongo.DESCENDING)
```

This example will give me discount value 1 and 10 but what i needed was 10 and 15, how can i sort before limiting (if possible) without losing performance (the collection is really big)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort()` gets applied first and then `limit`.

Scroll down to this doc: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

> The following statements chain cursor methods limit() and sort():
>
> db.bios.find().sort( { name: 1 } ).limit( 5 )
>
> db.bios.find().limit( 5
>   ).sort( { name: 1 } )
>
> The two statements are equivalent; i.e. the order in which you chain
>   the limit() and the sort() methods is not significant. Both statements
>   return the first five documents, as determined by the ascending sort
>   order on ‘name’.

**Sort order testing**

Sorting actually works correctly for me. Using `MongoDB shell version v3.6.3` on Ubuntu 18.04 server, I loaded a file like this:

```
[{"discount_value": 1, "name": "promotion_1", "category": ["X"]},
{"discount_value": 10, "name": "promotion_10", "category": ["X", "Y"]},
{"discount_value": 15, "name": "promotion_15", "category": ["X", "Y", "Z"]}]
```

using `mongoimport --db test --collection test1 --drop --file testing.txt --jsonArray`

From mongo prompt, I tried to find and sort on discount_value descending and saw that 15 was on the top.

```
> db.test1.find({"category": {"$in": ["X"]}}).sort( {discount_value: -1} )
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cb4beefea2d524413d8df57"), "discount_value" : 15, "name" : "promotion_15", "category" : [ "X", "Y", "Z" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cb4beefea2d524413d8df56"), "discount_value" : 10, "name" : "promotion_10", "category" : [ "X", "Y" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cb4beefea2d524413d8df55"), "discount_value" : 1, "name" : "promotion_1", "category" : [ "X" ] }
```

**Limit testing**

Notice how `limit` being before or after `sort` doesn't a difference in the output.

Limit after sort gives the same result as limit before sort.

```
> db.test1.find({"category": {"$in": ["X"]}}).sort( {discount_value: -1} ).limit(2)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cb4beefea2d524413d8df57"), "discount_value" : 15, "name" : "promotion_15", "category" : [ "X", "Y", "Z" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cb4beefea2d524413d8df56"), "discount_value" : 10, "name" : "promotion_10", "category" : [ "X", "Y" ] }
```

vs.

```
> db.test1.find({"category": {"$in": ["X"]}}).limit(2).sort( {discount_value: -1} )
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cb4beefea2d524413d8df57"), "discount_value" : 15, "name" : "promotion_15", "category" : [ "X", "Y", "Z" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cb4beefea2d524413d8df56"), "discount_value" : 10, "name" : "promotion_10", "category" : [ "X", "Y" ] }
```

**Sorting performance**

The best I can tell you is to use indexes as suggested in their manual https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/ and use explain to understand where query bottlenecks exists for your kind of workload with https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/#db.collection.explain